# Evaluate passed object in function only

Tags: c#, appium

I want to pass an object to a C# function, so that it is evaluated in the function and not before.
Is this possible?

Background: I want to check if a specific WindowsElement is visible for a UI test. When evaluating this Element when it it not available (yet) an exception is thrown.

When I write a function that expects this WindowsElement as an argument, it is evaluated before the function call. But then I can't write a try/catch block around it.

```
public static bool IsVisible(WindowsElement windowsElement) {
    try {
        return windowsElement.Displayed;
    }
    catch {
        return false;
    }
}
```

As a *workaround* I created a **func delegate** that has no input parameters and returns a bool. A disadvantage of this approach is that the check is very long and I would have to insert this Func delegate for each WindowsElement again.

```
Func<bool> isElementVisible = () => {
    try {
        return UIControls.MyWindowsElement.Displayed;
    }
    catch {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Is there any way to combine both approaches?

Answer (score 0):

you could write extension method to check the visibility

```
  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var element = new WindowsElement(null, "test");                       
        var isVisible = element.IsVisible();
        Console.WriteLine(isVisible);
    }
}



public static class WindowsElementExtensions
{
     public static bool IsVisible(this WindowsElement windowsElement)
{
    try
    {
        return windowsElement.Displayed;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This will throw an exception when calling element.IsVisible(), because this element does not exist when calling the function.

Comment: well you could avoid by adding null check `element?.IsVisible()`

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't help either, because the exception is thrown when searching for the element.

Comment: would you able to duplicate the behaviour here? https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Comment: .ctor has exception, not sure that was intentional , the sample provided no one can resolve.

Comment: Yes, that is intentional. That also describes my initial question. I wanted to know if it is somehow possible that the expression is first evaluated in the function (with the try/catch block) itself.